# Is it a good idea to use a virtual machine as an external facing code repository server

Tags: networking, virtualbox, debian, git, firewall

I've set up (installed git/configured certs (disabled password login)/synced repos) a debian box vm with a bridged adapter. Now it's running on Windows server 2016; inbound connections are blocked by an external firewall.

Is it a good idea to add a firewall exception for the vm so that outsourcing teams can work on the repos directly?

Answer (score 1):

Given a proper firewall setup and hardening of the machine there's absolutely no problem with that approach.

I'd say it's even better than running it bare-metal because you have an additional layer of isolation between the host and VM.